# prepareForSegue sending the wrong (delayed) string extracted from array to second view controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7

In VC1, I am trying to extract a string from an array, and send it to VC2. I do this in my prepareForSegue method. However, when I run it, there is a lag:

1. I tap row1(apples) in VC1 it goes to VC2 and shows apples in VC2
2. Tap back to VC 1
3. Tap row2(bananas), string passes as apples to
   VC2
4. Tap back to VC1
5. I tap row3(oranges) in VC1 it goes to VC2
   and shows bananas in VC2
   etc etc.

Below is the code I am using. If anyone could help show me where I am going wrong, it would be much appreciated. Thank you..

```
class HomeSearchViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchBarDelegate {

var filteredArray = [String]()
var shouldShowSearchResults = false
var searchController: UISearchController!

var databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
var loggedInUser = AnyObject?()
var loggedInUserData = AnyObject?()


var productSearchArray = [AnyObject?]()
var productBrandArray = [String]()
var itemNameArray = [String]()
var picUrlArray = [String]()
var skuArray = [String]()
var nextScreenRow = Int()
var nextSceenRowNonSearch = Int()
var toPass = String()
var toPassSearch = String()
var initialSearchList = ["Apple", "Samsung", "Windows", "Google"]

    @IBOutlet weak var tblSearchResults: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        loadListOfCountries()
        configureSearchController()


        tblSearchResults.delegate = self
        tblSearchResults.dataSource = self
    }

// MARK: Table Cells Stuff

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if shouldShowSearchResults {
            return filteredArray.count
        }
        else {
            return initialSearchList.count
        }
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("homeSearchCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! HomeSearchTableViewCell

      //note to self: need to pass on more than one variable for search

        if shouldShowSearchResults {

            cell.configure(filteredArray[indexPath.row], itemNameLabel: "text'", skuLabel: "TEXT")
            //cell.textLabel?.text = filteredArray[indexPath.row]
        }
        else if shouldShowSearchResults == false{
            cell.configureNISearch(initialSearchList[indexPath.row])

        }

        return cell
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 60.0
    }
```

//to find out row and pass variable.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)


    //println("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")spDetailSegue
    if shouldShowSearchResults {
        nextScreenRow = indexPath.row

        // get to the next screen
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("spDetailSegue", sender: self)

    }
    else if shouldShowSearchResults == false{

        nextSceenRowNonSearch = indexPath.row

        // get to the next screen
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("searchSegue", sender: self)
    }

}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {



    if (segue.identifier == "spDetailSegue") {
        //Checking identifier is crucial as there might be multiple
        // segues attached to same view
        let detailVC = segue.destinationViewController as? pDetailViewController;
        detailVC!.toPassSku = skuArray[nextScreenRow]

        // print("vSku", )
    }
    if (segue.identifier == "searchSegue"){

        //print("selected indexpath = ", selectedIndex)
        let detailVC = segue.destinationViewController as? SearchDetailViewController;
        detailVC!.toPassSearch = initialSearchList[nextSceenRowNonSearch]
    }

}
```

//Search Bar stuff

```
func configureSearchController() {
        // Initialize and perform a minimum configuration to the search controller.

        searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search here..."
        searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
        searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        //searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = ["Products", "Users"]
        searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        searchController.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
        // Place the search bar view to the tableview headerview.
        tblSearchResults.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
    }

    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        shouldShowSearchResults = true
        tblSearchResults.reloadData()
    }


    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        shouldShowSearchResults = false
        tblSearchResults.reloadData()
    }

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        if !shouldShowSearchResults {
            shouldShowSearchResults = true
            tblSearchResults.reloadData()
        }

        searchController.searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
        let searchString = searchController.searchBar.text

        // Filter the data array and get only those countries that match the search text.
        filteredArray = itemNameArray.filter({ (item_name) -> Bool in
            let countryText: NSString = item_name

            return (countryText.rangeOfString(searchString!, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch).location) != NSNotFound
        })

        // Reload the tableview.
        tblSearchResults.reloadData()
    }
```

}

Comment: Is there anywhere else in your code that is assigning values to nextScreenRow? More code may help here, this seems good to me.

Comment: adding more code. to answer your question I declared it as a variable. `code`var nextScreenRow = Int()

Comment: Could you email me the file? I wouldn't mind trying to solve it, but I can't seem to see the issue here.

Comment: Hi Dallas, i can certainly do that-- i appreciate your assistance. could you please send me your email?

Comment: are you sure that didSelectRowAtIndexPath is called before prepareForSegue? you did not put your segue action from cell to controller?

Comment: @Lu_ that worked! I incorrectly hooked it up on the storyboard (cell -> vc, instead of vc-> vc). Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @Lu_  suggested,

> are you sure that didSelectRowAtIndexPath is called before prepareForSegue? you did not put your segue action from cell to controller?

This solved the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

once try by removing below line

```
  tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
```

from your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: I thought that line might be the issue as well. I know I've had the issue once before accidentally using the auto complete on the delegate method "didDeselectRowAtIndexPath"

Comment: they delay is still happening